# Calculate real surface area with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, area

I would like to know if its possible to calculate a real surface area (with DEM information) only with PostGis function ? 
I know it's possible with Saga and Grass.

Comment: if its a raster you can load the raster into postgres and convert the raster to vector to calculate the area